# R: Can I read a vector and use the value to assign another vector?

Tags: r, string, function, matrix, vector

In R, I have a vector anno_ref_seq, rows containing values like the following

```
c("NM_026671", "NP_080947"), c("NM_027853", "NP_082129"), c("NM_025791", "NP_080067")
```

I want to take each value, say, `*c("NM_026671", "NP_080947")*`, and take the first element "`NM_026671`" and assign it to a variable, so that I can use it again. So from each row, I want pick the first element and create another vector.

If I can read each row as `a = c("NM_026671", "NP_080947")`, where `b` is returned as vector containing two elements, that would help, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could yield a vector b by changing x to a data.frame:

```
x[1, ] <- c("NM_026671", "NP_080947")
x[2, ] <- c("NM_027853", "NP_082129")
x[3, ] <- c("NM_025791", "NP_080067")
dx <- as.data.frame(x)
b <- as.vector(dx[, 1])
```